# My program stop itself in a part of code. How to fix it?

Tags: c, cycle-detection

I am doing a program that verifies a cycle in a tree. It's fine with small data, but when data increasing, it stops. Help me, please.

```
Cromosoma *kruskalModificado(Gen *setGenes, int numGenes, int numVertices, Cromosoma *cromosoma){
int **matrizAux=NULL;
matrizAux=inicializarMatriz(matrizAux,numVertices);
int *posicionesFinales=(int *) calloc(numVertices,sizeof(*posicionesFinales));
int *vecGenes=(int*) calloc(numVertices,sizeof(*vecGenes));
int listo;
int indiceRandom,elegidos=0;
while(elegidos<numVertices-1){//Itero hasta que todos los vertices hayan sido agregados al arbol
    indiceRandom=rand()%numGenes;//Indice aleatorio de mi conjunto de genes
    if(vecGenes[indiceRandom]==1)
        continue;
    vecGenes[indiceRandom]=1;
    Gen genAux=setGenes[indiceRandom];//Obtengo el gen
    //Verifico que vertice aun no ha sido agregado y lo agrego a mi conjunto de componentes.
    listo=1;
    int *visitados=(int *) calloc(numVertices,sizeof(*visitados));
    valido(matrizAux,numVertices,genAux.v1,genAux.v2,&listo,visitados);
    free(visitados);
    printf("Aqui\n");
    if(listo==0)
        continue;
    (*cromosoma).genes[(*cromosoma).numGenes]=genAux;
    (*cromosoma).numGenes++;
    (*cromosoma).fitnessValue+=genAux.peso;
    elegidos++;
    matrizAux[genAux.v1][posicionesFinales[genAux.v1]]=genAux.v2;
    matrizAux[genAux.v2][posicionesFinales[genAux.v2]]=genAux.v1;
    posicionesFinales[genAux.v1]++;
    posicionesFinales[genAux.v2]++;
}
free(posicionesFinales);
free(vecGenes);
for(int i=0 ; i < numVertices; i ++)
    free(matrizAux[i]);
return (Cromosoma *)cromosoma;
```

}

Here another part of code.

```
void valido(int **matriz, int numVertices, int genInicial, int genFinal,int *listo, int *visitados){
if(genInicial==genFinal){
    (*listo)=0;
    return ;
}
int j=0;
visitados[genInicial]=1;
while(matriz[genInicial][j]!=-1 && j<numVertices &&(*listo)==1){
    if(visitados[matriz[genInicial][j]]==0){
        valido(matriz,numVertices,matriz[genInicial][j],genFinal,listo,visitados);
    }

    j++;
}
return ;
}
```

Valido function helps me to detect a cycle in a given edge.

Comment: what's the error?

Comment: When I run the program, it work fine, in other cases, its stop itself  say me "Process returned -1073741819 (0xC0000005)"

Comment: And I don't know where is the error.

Comment: `0xc0000005` means the program has accessed invalid memory. To fix this the first step is to find where the problem occurs. Run the program in a debugger. It will immediately tell you which line of triggers the crash and allows stepping thru the code and examining the state.

Comment: Review `int *vecGenes=(int*) calloc(numVertices,sizeof(*vecGenes)); ... indiceRandom=rand()%numGenes; if(vecGenes[indiceRandom]==1) ...`

Comment: Thank you so much. I solved my problem. in int *vecGenes=(int*) calloc(numVertices,sizeof(*vecGenes)); .. is not numVertices, but numGenes.

Comment: Please make this an answer to let others know that your problem is solved. And then come back and mark it. Please take the [tour] to learn how to use StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

In int vecGenes=(int) calloc(numVertices,sizeof(*vecGenes)); .. is not numVertices, but numGenes.